# Nudge/reposition geom_labels individually or via aesthetic?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot responses to a series of Likert-type questions using ggplot(). I've calculated proportions for each response ("Strongly agree", "Agree", etc.) to each question using dplyr, and now want to plot the proportions in a stacked bar graph (one bar per question). The code below gives an idea of what I have so far.

```r
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(Question = "Q1", 
                  Response = LETTERS[1:5], 
                  freq = c(.01, .03, .11, .35, .5),
                  offset = c(.5, .25, 0, 0, 0))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = Question, y = freq, fill = Response, label = Response)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_label(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

I need to include labels for each response showing the proportion; my problem arises because very few respondents disagree/strongly disagree, which means that the bars for these responses are too small to contain the labels (see A and B in the example), and they overlap.

I want to offset the labels for specific responses by a fixed amount, so that they don't overlap. Intuitively, I hoped something like this would work:

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Question, y = freq, fill = Response, label = Response)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_label(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), nudge_x = offset)
```

But this returns "Error: You must specify either `position` or `nudge_x`/`nudge_y`."

I've tried using the vjust aesthetic, but this doesn't shift the labels enough to solve the problem.

Any suggestions on how to reposition geom_labels by an aesthetic? Please let me know if you'd like any additional information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. "Error: You must specify either position or nudge_x/nudge_y."**

The error is pretty self-explanatory you cannot use `nudge_x` in combination with `position_stack` its either one or the other since both are options for the same `position` parameter:

From [ggplot2 source code](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/geom-text.r):

```
  if (!missing(nudge_x) || !missing(nudge_y)) {
    if (!missing(position)) {
      stop("You must specify either `position` or `nudge_x`/`nudge_y`.", call. = FALSE)
    }

    position <- position_nudge(nudge_x, nudge_y)
  }
```

**2. Any suggestions on how to reposition geom_labels by an aesthetic?**

```
dat <- data.frame(Question = "Q1", 
                  Response = LETTERS[1:5], 
                  freq = c(.01, .03, .11, .35, .5),
                  offset = c(.03, 0, 0, 0, 0))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = Question, y = freq, fill = Response, label = Response)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_label(aes(y = freq + offset), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

You can change the aesthetics by calling `aes` again in the `geom_label` call, here I added `offset` to the original frequency (**note** that I also changed the offset values in your dataframe to produce a better plot):

[image]